# what the differce between rails -d and nohup rails server &

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am wondering what's the difference between using

```
rails server -d
```

and using

```
nohup rails server &
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that they are basically equivalent - they will both detach the rails server process. However, they will log their output to different files - the first to a log file such as `log/development.log`, the second to `nohup.out`.

Answer (score 2):

`-d` means `deamon` which means that the server is running in the background instead of the console.